# Odoo - Filter Dropdown based on Roles within a project

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have an issue with a functionality i have a dropdown that get populated based on a Many2one field and should display all the roles created for a particular project, and it works fine when a create for the first time the entry it brings the elements that is supposed to, but when I hit "Edit" and try to change the role the dropdown displays all the roles in the system.

```
# In the model this is how we fetch the roles per project.
role_id = fields.Many2one('project.task', required=True ,string='Role')

def _get_tasks_ids(self):
        tasks = self.env['project.task'].search([('project_id', '=', self.env.context.get('default_project_id'))])
        logging.info(tasks)
        if tasks:
            return tasks.ids
        else:
            return []
    
    @api.onchange('role_id')
    def fetch_task_ids(self):
        task_list = self._get_tasks_ids()
        if len(task_list)>0:
            return {'domain': {'role_id': [('id', 'in', task_list)] }}
        else:
            # return empy list by default
            return {'domain': {'role_id': [('id', '=', -1)]}}
```

```
# the view
<group name="project_discounts_bottom" string="Role level adjustments" colspan="2">
                            <field name="discount_ids" string="" context="{'default_project_id':id}" widget="one2many_list">
                                <tree editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="discount_type" widget="selection"/>
                                    <field name ='adjustment_type' widget="selection" />
                                    <field name="discount_value" />
                                    <field name="role_id" />
                                    <field name="discount_date_start" />
                                    <field name="discount_date_end" />
                                </tree>
                                 <form>
                                    <field name="discount_type" widget="selection" />
                                    <field name ='adjustment_type' widget="selection" />
                                    <field name="discount_value" />
                                    <field name="role_id" domain="[('project_id','=','project.id')]" />
                                    <field name="discount_date_start" />
                                    <field name="discount_date_end" />
                                </form>
                            </field>
                        </group>
```

What may be causing this only when I edit the entry?

Comment: This is the drawback of on-change. You've two options to achieve the requirement: 1. Remove create and edit option from many2one field. 2. Instead of using on-change you create a new field which will contain ids then use domain in xml.